# Как отображать изображения внутри события fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, firebase, fullcalendar

Как создавать события и внутри отображать изображения?
Использую базу данных firebase и чистый js.
Давно задаюсь этим вопросом.
Объясните или может есть какие-то примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  editable: true,
  dateClick: (info) => {
    calendar.addEvent({
      title: 'Привет',
      start: info.dateStr,
      image_url: 'https://picsum.photos/50'
    });
  },
  eventContent: (arg) => {
    const imgUrl = arg.event._def.extendedProps.image_url;
    const imgNode = document.createElement('img');
    imgNode.src = imgUrl;
    
    const title = arg.event._def.title;
    const titleNode = document.createElement('h4');
    titleNode.innerHTML = title;

    const arrNodes = [titleNode, imgNode];

    return {
      domNodes: arrNodes
    };
  },
  dayMaxEvents: 2,
  locale: 'ru'
});

calendar.render();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.fc .fc-toolbar-title {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}

.fc .fc-button {
  font-size: 0.75em !important;
}

.fc-daygrid-event-harness {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fc-event-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fc-event-main > * + * {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/locales-all.min.js"></script>
```